# How to run a single row of a Cucumber scenario outline example table in RubyMine?

Tags: cucumber, rubymine

I'm running tests using RubyMine (forced upon me).

I have some features that use the Scenario Outline and Example format.

Is there a way I can run only a certain row from the Example table?

Example:

```
 Examples:
  | user_row | row1 | row2 |
  | 1        | 2    | 4    |
  | 51       | 51   | 97   |
  | 98       | 98   | 147  |
```

I only want to run the test from the 2nd row (user_row 51).

I can't seem to find anything with the help in RubyMine for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cucumber itself does support running a single example. RubyMine doesn't support it in a nice way, but you can do it with a little extra effort.

To run a single Cucumber example from the command line:

```
cucumber -f features/your.feature:##
```

where ## is the line number (over the entire file, not just within the example table) of the example that you want to run.

Disappointingly, RubyMine's Cucumber runner doesn't allow you to run a single line of a Cucumber example: invoking the "Run context configuration" command (control-shift-R in the Mac keymap I'm using) on an example row runs the whole file (it doesn't even just run that scenario), and there's no way to add a line number to a Cucumber run configuration (if you add it to the end of the file name you get an error).

However, you can manually create a generic run configuration which runs a single example:

- Run → Edit Configurations
- Click + and choose Gem Command
- Enter "Gem name" "cucumber", "Executable name" "cucumber", and "Arguments" "features/your.feature:##" (with the appropriate line number in place of ##).
- Hit OK
- To run that configuration, click the Run button or type control-R. To debug, click the Debug button or type control-D.

Someone has already filed [a request for this feature to be explicitly supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16008) with JetBrains which you can vote for.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've been using it via command line for years and prefer that approach, I'm not a fan of IDE's at all.

Comment: Apologies, thought I had

Comment: I hear you about running from the command line.. that's my preference also.     OTOH there are a huge number of benefits to using rubymine when working on cucumber, more than I could list in this comment.. although I'll say that being able to control-click on a step in a feature to jump to the step definition is perhaps one of the most useful.

Comment: Thank you. It works the same even fr Angular E2E tests using Cucumber with Protractor.