# How to run a single specflow scenario outline using nunit3 console tool

Tags: specflow, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

Using VS2015 the Test Explorer allows you to run a single scenario outline.

[image: Test Explorer]

Now I need to do the same using NUnit3 console tool (I'm using NUnit as Unit Test Provider).

Currently I'm using the following command in order to run a test using console tool.

```
"C:\NUnit-3.0.1\bin\nunit3-console.exe" Path.Scripts.dll --test:Fully.Qualified.Name.TestAAAFeature.TestAAA --x86
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could run a single row of a specflow scenario outline example using the `--testlist:` option.

```
# list.txt
TestC112169Feature.TestCase112169("1","atomic",null)

# cmd
"C:\NUnit-3.0.1\bin\nunit3-console.exe" Path.Scripts.dll --testlist:"c:\list.txt" --x86
```

And that do the trick.

Comment: can this be used for `vstest.console` ? If yes , do you know where can I find the syntax for defining test in a file , like you did in `list.txt`

Answer (score 0):

First and foresmost, I think you should rename your test cases to be more informative as a best practice.

Coming to your question, you should use **filters** which can be specified by using a *where* clause. For running a specific test case, you can use either *method* or *name* to filter down to one or more target test case(s).

Just append the following to your command and you should be good to go.

```
--where "name == 'TestCase11257'"
```

OR

```
--where "method == 'TestCase11257'"
```

or you can even combine multiple filters like

```
--where "name == 'TestCase11257' || method == 'TestCase11257'"
```

You can read more about filters [here](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language)

Comment: The name of the tests is a team convention due we have around 10000 test cases in the backlog, so its easy to looks for the test using its TFS id. And, well I tried to use nunit filters in order to run a single test of a scenario outline example, there is a way splitting the rows and adding a different category to each one of the rows. but I was looking for a way more like the one in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651067/how-to-run-a-single-row-of-a-cucumber-scenario-outline-example-table-in-rubymine.)